# Where to store IPFS hash other than infura.io without paying

Tags: blockchain, ethereumjs, ipfs

I used infura.io to store IPFS hash few months ago in my Ethereum dapp based on React JS but now it's not free anymore and it is asking for my bank account details. I want to use it for small personal project and don't want to risk adding bank account details for storing IPFS hash.

Answer (score 6):

You can use alternative services like [web3.storage](https://web3.storage/pricing/) (5Gb free space) or [Pinata](https://www.pinata.cloud/pricing) (1Gb free space, 1Gb bandwidth).

Please note the best practice is to use your own IPFS node to distribute data, in parallel optionally with other external pinning services. This way, there will always be at least one node active, and the risk of your users being unable to access the content is reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Filebase has 5GB free - https://filebase.com - They have an S3-Compatible API and are very fast from my testing